# BitmapImage and Uri for local file (WinRT store app)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bitmapimage

I am attempting to display an image that lives on my c: drive.  The code below shows how I handle two images: image 1 is local and image 2 is from the web.

Image 1 fails to display, image 2 works perfectly. Why does image 1 fail to display?

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Image 1 - lives on local disk
        var uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Frank\Pictures\MindMap.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(uri);
        testImage.Source = img; 

        // Image 2 - image lives on web 
        var uri2 = new Uri("http://www.mommyish.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/GwynethPaltrow.jpg");
        BitmapImage img2 = new BitmapImage(uri2);


        testImage2.Source = img2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Because app have limited access to the device/computer. This can be understand from this - for accessing `Pictures library` photos you have to add the `capability` to your app explicitly. You can understand this - as for security reasons too.

Suppose it has been displayed correctly but after some days someone has deleted it. then what happen to your app. It will crash. Or you can say app become dependent on the device to work.

So it is better that you understand the domain of an app and resources and capabilities of an app that is can use.
So first add image to your `YourAppFoder` then access it.